# ngFor not displaying data cause of asynchronous issues in the child component

Tags: angular

I have a simple Http request in a child component but it's not being displayed in the DOM when I loop through it using *ngFor cause initially the value is undefined.

When I have the same piece of code in the main component( App component) it displays it tho and I don't understand why.

I have tried using ASYN/AWAIT and other various ways but to no avail.

```
<div *ngFor="let i of arr">  <li>
  {{i.id}}
</li></div>
```

```
  url:string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  arr;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(){

      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(data => {
        this.arr = data
      console.log(this.arr);

      });

  }
```

the array is logged in the console but it doesn't display it in the DOM.

Comment: What is the output of the `console.log`?

Comment: Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lhyxhv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) it is working

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `async` pipe like this:

**Component TS file**

```
 url:string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  arr;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(){

      //If you expect that your API never return a null/undefined response
      //then remove filter operator
      this.arr = this.http.get(this.url).pipe(filter(r => !!r));    
  }
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of arr | async">  <li>
  {{i.id}}
</li></div>
```